# Blazor enable dynamic root components / Error: Dynamic root components have not been enabled in this application

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I want render a Blazor component from javascript.
See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/ "Render Blazor components from JavaScript"

I have a HTML file:

```
<script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>

<script>
    async function ready() {
        let containerElement = document.getElementById('counter');
        await Blazor.rootComponents.add(containerElement, 'counter', { incrementAmount: 10 });
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
```

And do

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.RootComponents.RegisterForJavaScript<Counter>("counter");
});
```

Error message (JavaScript):

```
test.html:14 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Dynamic root components have not been enabled in this application.
    at E (blazor.server.js:1)
    at Object.add (blazor.server.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.ready (test.html:8)
```

How can i enable dynamic root components?

Comment: I'm running into this as well. I'll try to share it to see if anyone can help us.
In case anyone wants a sample, this is for Blazor WASM, but same error: https://github.com/Swimburger/RenderBlazorFromJs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is happening because of the delay between the document loading and Blazor being "ready" to process your request to add a component.

There doesn't appear to be any official documented solution for this, but something like this is possible

Change Blazor to manual start:

##### index.html

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
```

Start Blazor, then try to add components - repeat until success

##### script.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startBlazor)

function startBlazor() {
    Blazor
        .start()
        .then(() => {
            requestAnimationFrame(AddBlazorComponents)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

let attempts = 0
const maxAttempts = 120 // arbitrary choice

function AddBlazorComponents() {
    if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
        // give up after trying too many times
        console.error("Could not load Blazor components.")
        return
    }

    const containerElement = document.querySelector('#app')
    Blazor.rootComponents.add(containerElement, 'app', {})
        .catch(reason => {
            if (reason.message === "Dynamic root components have not been enabled in this application.")
                requestAnimationFrame(AddBlazorComponents)
            else
                console.error(reason)
        })
    attempts++
}
```

#### Better solution?

You could, possibly, add a JSInterop call to your .NET code to facilitate this, after the application starts - but it would be different for the different hosting models : Blazor Server / Blazor WebAssembly.

Even better might be to make a PR to the aspnetcore repo with a method of pre-registering components for the framework to load when it is ready.

#### Update 29 sep 2021

It turns out there is some currently undocumented functionality that helps here. I have copied my comment from @Swimburger 's [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37074) below:

The new JavaScript Initializer `afterStarted` is called (potentially) too soon for Dynamic components, but it turns out you can pass an initializer to be called for a dynamic component - but it is not well documented or intuitive imho.

To make this work, I changed the app startup like this (adding `javaScriptInitializer: "loadApp"`) in program.cs:

`builder.RootComponents.RegisterForJavaScript<App>(identifier: "app", javaScriptInitializer: "loadApp");`

Then, and this is where it was non-intuitive, I added an export to my module (like `afterStarted`) called `loadApp` - but it wasn't called.

It turned out that `loadApp` is only found if I add it to the `window` object, so I added this to index.html

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>
    window.loadApp = function (component,params) {
        let containerElement = document.querySelector('#app')
        window.Blazor.rootComponents.add(containerElement, component, params)
    }
</script>
```

This feels like I am missing something in how to export my custom initializer OR it really does need to be added to `window` directly, which seems odd...

Comment: When I try this, I don't need to request animation frame logic to keep trying. It always works on the first try.
https://gist.github.com/Swimburger/c808f10bcb2c022c624aca233beecca1
Thank you for this solution!

Comment: I also created an issue on GitHub to see if we can make this more intuitive: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37074

Comment: @Swimburger I think you have been lucky or possibly using a different browser - I actually wrote/tested this using your github repo and definitely needed the retry logic - usually about 2 or 3 attempts before it was ready.

Comment: Odd, it always loads correctly every time I try it. I tried it in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.
I haven't tried on Safari. I also tried with slow 3G emulation in Chrome and no issues.
Could you give more details about your browser?

Comment: I was using Edge/Chrome/Firefox - I added a console log to AddBlazorComponents and saw it was logging 2/3 times